# Javascript - Using Math.round after percentage function

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have a calculation function being used to determine the percentage differences between two values in an array.

After doing my calculations the values that are being returned are in a decimal form such as

```
0: 6.439999737456044
​
1: 7.7490311455816805
​
2: 2.3720164855984383
​
3: 4.12554213772474
```

I am trying to round each number in the array to the nearest whole number. So index 0 = 6, index 1 = 8, index 2 = 2, index 3 = 4.

I am using math.round method at the end of my calculation and it has no effect on the numbers returning as they return as the decimals shown above.
​

here is my code:

```
const Numerators = [];
    const Denominators = [];
    Array.forEach(({ DataValue }, i) => {
        const arrToPushTo = i % 2 === 0 ? Denominators : Numerators;
        arrToPushTo.push(Number(DataValue.replace(/,/g, '')));
    });
    const Percentage = Numerators.map((Numerator, i) => {
        const Denominator = Denominators[i];
        return 100 * Math.abs((Denominator - Numerator) / ((Denominator + Numerator) / 2));
        math.Round(Percentage)
    });

console.log(Percentage)
```

I have also tried creating another variable `const Round = math.Round(Percentage)` but when console logging this variable I am returned back with `NaN`

Comment: This should work fine. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Also, you have a typo. Its actually `Math.round()`

Comment: You have to `return` the rounded percentage. `Math.round()` (and it's `Math`, not `math`) does not modify the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math.Round` doesn't mutate the original value. You need to assign the result to a variable or return it from a function. You want to move this out of the loop as well. Nothing after `return` in the loop will execute.

Something like:

```
const Percentage = Numerators.map((Numerator, i) => {
        const Denominator = Denominators[i];
        return 100 * Math.abs((Denominator - Numerator) / ((Denominator + Numerator) / 2));
    });

const percentages = Percentage.map((percent) => math.Round(percent));

console.log(percentages);
```

**EDIT:** I just saw that you have a return value already.

Adding some tidbits on general JavaScript code style:

- TitleCased var names are generally reserved for constructors, that is functions that create objects, and classes. If you're using TypeScript, you'll see it for types and interfaces as well. The big picture is that title case is used for entities.

  - default for variables and functions should be camelCase, except for the exception noted above.
- `Array` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a variable name. If you want to use `Array.prototype.forEach`, the syntax is `[1,2,3,4].forEach((num) => doSomething(num))`

Answer (score -1):

Just do `Math.floor(val)` or `~~val` if you’re dealing with non-negative numbers